# Azure Table WebAPI authorization using Shared Key

Tags: azure

I'm trying to use the WebAPI for Azure tables and I cannot find the mysterious 'Shared Key Authentication' required to issue requests.

This article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179428.aspx mentions that I should use Shared Key Authentication. However, in the portal I can only find a primary and secondary key. Using those do not work.

So the question is, how do I get the Shared Key Authentication from the Primary Key?

Thanks!

Comment: `SharedKey` and `SharedKeyLite` are authorization mechanisms you would use to authorize your requests against table storage (or for that matter Azure storage). This only comes into picture if you're writing wrapper over Azure Storage REST API. If you're using any client library, the library takes care of this for you. Please tell us what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hey thanks, I found the answer after fiddling and put it below.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found my answer after much fiddling. The SharedKeyLite just refers to what you sign, not the key used to sign. You can just use your primary key to sign:

`Sun, 11 Oct 2009 19:52:39 GMT\n/testaccount1/Tables`

... (replace testaccount1 with your real table name) and that will work. The problem was that the [help page for Create Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135729.aspx) states that it works with JSON, but it doesn't. Once I switched to XML it started working.